# Is there a way to migrate devise users from one application to another (still using devise?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a legacy rails app, with hundreds of users, using devise. I need to migrate these users to a brand new app, running devise and rails 3.2. What are some good ways to do this? How to deal with the encripted passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out device upgrade instructions
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0